# R Generate random numbers based on condition

Tags: r, vector, random

I'd like to generate a sequence of 100 numbers based on the following conditions -

- The numbers range from 1 to 5, and are whole numbers.
- The number of 1s and 2s generated as a percentage of the total equals 90%

**My Attempt**

I attempted to create the sequence using `runif`. However I am unsure about how to include the second condition.

```
v=c(1,2,3,4,5)
rep(sample(v),100)
```

Your help on the second condition would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by @markus, you may use the `prob` argument for this. Here is another idea

```
v <- sample(c(sample(1:2, 90, replace = TRUE), sample(3:5, 10, replace = TRUE)))
```

First generate the 90% (i.e. here 90 elements) consisting of `1,2` and the remaining 10% (that is 10) separately, and then shuffle the result.

And obviously,

```
length(which(v %in% 1:2)) / length(v)
# [1] 0.9
```

**Edit**

Here the more general case

```
# size of final vector
n <- 100
# percentages
p1 <- 0.935
p2 <- 1 - p1
# calculate number of elements (using round)
n1 <- round(p1*n)
n2 <- n - n1
# get final vector
v <- sample(c(sample(1:2, n1, replace = TRUE), sample(3:5, n2, replace = TRUE)))

# Note:
length(which(v %in% 1:2)) / length(v)
# [1] 0.94
```

Note that you could have the exact percentage for example by setting `n <- 100*10`.

Comment: Thanks nate. And how does this method work if the percentage is a decimal (say 93.5%) instead of 90%?

Comment: @Varun Well since you cannot have (*exactly*) 93.5 elements to be in `1:2`, we must round or ceil or something. I'll add an edit in my answer.